# Concatenating two tables in pandas, giving preference to one for identical indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two data sets df1 and df2. Rows with unique indices are always copied, rows with duplicate indices should always be picked from df1. Imagine two time series, and df2 has additional data but is of lesser quality than df1, so ideally data comes from df1, but I'm willing to backfill from df2

df1:

```
date         value   v2
2020/01/01   df1-1   x
2020/01/03   df1-3   y
```

df2:

```
date         value   v2
2020/01/02   df2-2   a
2020/01/03   df2-3   b
2020/01/04   df2-4   c
```

are combined into

```
date         value   v2
2020/01/01   df1-1   x
2020/01/02   df2-2   a
2020/01/03   df1-3   y
2020/01/04   df2-4   c
```

The best I've got so far is

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how="outer",left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('','_y'))
df['value'] = result_df['value'].combine_first(result_df['value_y'])
df['v2'] = result_df['v2'].combine_first(result_df['v2'])
df=df[['value', 'v2']]
```

That gets the job done, but it seems unnecessarily clunky. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote *rows with unique indices* but you didn't show them,
so I assume that *date* column should be treated as these indices.

Furthermore, I noticed that all values in your DataFrames are not *NaN*.
If you guaratee this, you can run:

```
df1.set_index('date').combine_first(df2.set_index('date'))\
    .reset_index()
```

Steps:

- `combine_first` - combine both DataFrames based on values
   in their *date* columns.
- `reset_index` - change *date* column (for now the index) into
  a "regular" column.

## Another possible approach

If both your DataFrames have "standard" index (consecutive numbers starting
from *0*) and you want to keep only rows for **just these** unique indices,
you can run:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index')\
    .set_index('index')
df.index.name = None
```

But then the result is:

```
        date  value v2
0 2020-01-01  df1-1  x
1 2020-01-03  df1-3  y
2 2020-01-04  df2-4  c
```

so it is **different** from what you presented as *are combined into*
(as I assume - your expected result). This time you lost the row
with *v2 == 'a'*.

## Yet another approach

Based also on the assumption that all values in your DataFrames are not *NaN*:

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

The result will be just as the previous one.